# After update and can't access with ssh

Tags: ssh

I keep getting `Operation timed out` when trying to ssh the RPi from my Mac. The ssh was correctly working until last reboot. What should I do to try to save the house before reflashing the SD?

Comment: Can you see the Pi on your network? Can you tell if it has booted properly? Does ssh -vvv pi@piip tell you anything you didn't already know?

Comment: No, it is not connected to the router. I have a static IP for the RPi, also I know the RPi mac. Checking the router, the RPi is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Then connect it to a Screen/monitor, power cycle and see why it's not booting.

Answer (score 2):

> What should I do to try to save the house before reflashing the SD?

**You should plug a monitor and keyboard into it and boot it that way to see what is happening.**  At least a monitor, if you don't have a keyboard.

Reflashing the SD card is NOT a good solution to every single problem and roadblock.  For starters, it means you have given up on trying to figure out *why* there is a problem, so if it is because of something you've done wrong, there's no reason you won't just do it again.  If it is not your fault, there's still no reason "whatever it is" won't just happen again.

You have to learn to troubleshoot.

Comment: I don't have a monitor to connect. But I can plug the SD in my Mac an mount it (I successfully did it it) with fuse-ext2

Comment: If you can mount the SD card elsewhere, then you can check the logs (probably `/var/log/syslog`).  The issue with that is, if there's a fatal problem that occurs before the root filesystem is mounted read-write, then the problem never gets logged.  So have a look, and if there's no clue, bang on a neighbour's door and tell them you need some sugar and a few minutes alone with an HDMI TV ;)

Comment: Yes, apparently problem is with the filesystem. The last entry of the log is my shutdown after upgrading and installing netatalk and avahi-daemon.

Comment: `Oct 20 19:42:50 raspberrypi shutdown[21401]: shutting down for system halt
Oct 20 19:42:50 raspberrypi init: Switching to runlevel: 0
Oct 20 19:42:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[3329]: Got SIGTERM, quitting.
Oct 20 19:42:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[3329]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.100.
Oct 20 19:42:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[3329]: avahi-daemon 0.6.31 exiting.
Oct 20 19:42:53 raspberrypi ifplugd(eth0)[1590]: Exiting.`

Comment: Any benefit in running a disk check on the SD from an Ubuntu virtual box?

Comment: Wait a minute. Am I not suppose to have a `/boot/config.txt`? There's nothing in the `boot` folder...

Comment: `/boot` is a mount point; there are two partitions in the image and the first one gets mounted there.  So when you look at the second (larger, ext4) partition on another system, `/boot` is empty because nothing is mounted on it.  `config.txt` will be in the first (smaller, FAT32) partition. WRT checking the partitions (e.g. via `fsck`), yes absolutely do that.